# Why does checkbox in ion list not update until user scrolls

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

In the ion-list the UI for the ion-checkboxes don't update if the ion-checkbox implements two way binding through `[(ngModel)]="xxx"` until the user attempts to scroll. This occurs even when there are only 5 items in ion-list. Ion-checkboxes function normally without that implementation of two way binding. Tested using ionic serve command on Mozilla, Chrome, and Safari.

Minimal Example for `ionic start xxx blank --v2` project.

---

home.html

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list [virtualScroll]="listItems">
    <ion-item *virtualItem="let item">
      <ion-label>{{ item.number }}</ion-label>
      <ion-checkbox item-right [(ngModel)]="item.select">{{item.select}}</ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

---

home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  listItems = [{}];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      var listItem = {select: null, number: i};
      this.listItems.push(listItem);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This happens with exactly the code above to initialize `listItems`?

Comment: Yes, it's TypeScript but the type is defined for listItems with `listItems = [{}];` The home.html includes standard ion code that remains unchanged. But replacing the 'hello world' blank template in ionic replicates this error.

Comment: does it happen without `virtualscroll`? https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/virtual-scroll/VirtualScroll/

Comment: No, I changed the code to angular2's`<ion-list *ngFor="let item of listItems">
    <ion-item>` instead of the ionic suggestion above and it functions as a normal checkbox while still updating ngModel. Thank you, I still would like to understand the issue with `vituralscroll`, I know it has performance advantages but this will work!

Comment: @suraj I forgot to tag, *update*

Comment: I am unsure but it could be because items are going beyond scroll area? check section on `bufferRatio` in the link